# Is there a better way to have a Swift array with names associated to index numbers?

Tags: swift

In Swift, I want to have an array of items and then to be able to access those items by name or by index. The array is a fixed size array with 3 elements.

I have the following implementation using a `struct`

```
struct Boxes {
    var array: [Int]!
    var a: Int {
        get { return array[0] }
        set { array[0] = newValue }
    }
    var b: Int {
        get { return array[1] }
        set { array[1] = newValue }
    }
    var c: Int {
        get { return array[2] }
        set { array[2] = newValue }
    }
    init() {
        self.array = Array<Int>(repeating: 0, count: 3)
    }
}
```

And then, use it as follows:

```
var box = Boxes()
box.a = 1
box.b = box.array[0]
box.array[0] = 2
box.b = box.a
```

Is there a simpler, more elegant/concise form to do this?

Comment: This doesn't really achieve anything. `.a`, `.b` and `.c` is no more descriptive than `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`

Comment: Do you just hate writing those computed property declarations?

Comment: This is an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve by making a struct with both named elements, and numerical indices?

Comment: @Alexander unless you need to iterate through them somewhere else.

Comment: @FridayPie you could make a `var elements: [Int] { return [a, b, c] }`. If performance is a concern, you can implement an iterator and conform to `Sequence`

Comment: @Alexander. don't think it is an XY Problem.  Is not like I am trying to do A, and don't know how and instead I'm trying B, so I ask about B.  The question is about an explicit thing to accomplish: Is there a more elegant way to access an item in an array associating names to indices?  (vs. the provided code using enums).   Agree with you that both (names and indices are equally descriptive), but in this particular case I need to access them through their name (for educational purposes in the code to develop) and via the index (for parsing a binary pattern to match possible Int equivalents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Boxes {

    var array: [Int] {
        get { return [a, b, c] }
        set { (a, b, c) = (newValue[0], newValue[1], newValue[2]) }
    }

    var (a, b, c) = (0, 0 ,0)
}
```

Note that it is based on this sentence: **fixed size array with 3 elements**

Exact same usage:

```
var box = Boxes()
box.a = 1
box.b = box.array[0]
box.array[0] = 2
box.b = box.a
```

**Extra:**
You can add custom initializer if you want to init with an array:

```
init(array: [Int] = [0, 0, 0]) {
    self.array = array
}
```

Comment: I like the proposal.  It reduces the number of code lines by half. The only issue is that I need to assign the initial values to the array via the setter and not in the init() with "var box = Boxes(a: 0, b: 0, c: 0)"    Other than that it is nice

Comment: Hi @Mojtaba Hosseini, I see the edits to have (a, b, c) declared in the same line with the initial values.   It works perfectly

Comment: You could mention that. But don't worry, I updated my answer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Unless something simpler comes up, it will be the accepted one

Comment: You can also use tuple directly like this: `var box = (a: 0, b: 0, c: 0)` then both `box.a` and `box.1` are same, but you will loose array capabilities. If you are interested, I can make it as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an enum to store name-to-index associations, and add a subscript to `Boxes` to access the array:

```
enum BoxName : Int {
    case a, b, c
}

struct Boxes {
    var array: [Int]!

    subscript(_ name: BoxName) -> Int {
        get { return array[name.rawValue] }
        set { array[name.rawValue] = newValue }
    }

    init() {
        self.array = Array<Int>(repeating: 0, count: 3)
    }
}

// usage:

var box = Boxes()
box[.a] = 1
box[.b] = box.array[0]
box.array[0] = 2
box[.b] = box[.a]
```

Now when you want to add a new element and a new name in the array, you just need to add a new enum case.

Comment: Thx @Sweeper.  It reduces the number of lines, but I want to access the values using the simple dot notation (e.g. box.a = box.b).